# Compare each member of a vector with its number

Tags: r

The problem might be simple, but I cant solve it:
I got numeric vector, i need to compare its maximum/2 with each member except its maximum and if all these comparisons are FALSE , a=a+1.
I got these:

```
comp=c(6.674971, 11.208241, 18.296459, 5.165752, 123.000000)
a=0
if (max(comp)/2<comp[comp < max(comp)]){
a=a+1
}
a
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: like this `a <- ifelse(all(max(comp)/2 < comp[comp != max(comp)]), a+1, a)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The condition is true if :

```
 sum(2*comp > max(comp)) ==1
```

In this case , I would write it like this without using  `ìf`:

```
 a <- (sum(2*comp > max(comp)) ==1) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to add 1 every time you find a item bigger than max/2, which is what I am showing you. In case you want all to be false, add this line at the end.

```
if (a>0)
    a=1;
```

I think this will work, haven't compiled it because here I don't have R compiler, but this is the idea:

```
comp=c(6.674971, 11.208241, 18.296459, 5.165752, 123.000000)
a=0
temp=comp/max(comp)
for (n in 1:length(comp))
   { if ((temp(i)>max(comp)/2)&&(temp(i)!1))
        a=a+1
   }
```

Hope it helps.